# Evaluating two JSON string values incorrectly

Tags: javascript, json

I have two JSON objects, one that holds a list of main school names, and another that holds a list of all school names. For instance, say "Programming School" has four locations. So you have Programming school in one JSON Object, and then Programming School (Alaska),Programming School (Mass),Programming School (Florida),Programming School (California). I want to compare "Programming School" to all four locations, so I go through a loop, split everything at the "(" and take everything to the left. So I should find that I have Programming School == Programming School four times.

index.html

```
<li ng-repeat="x in collegeList" >
  <a class="list-item" href="who.html" id="{{x.collegeID}}" ng-click="getButtonClicked(x.collegeID,x.collegeName)">
    <h3 class="name">
      <span><img src="{{x.imagePath}}"  alt="School Icon"> </span>{{x.collegeName}}
    </h3>
  </a>
</li>
```

displayData.js

```
$scope.getButtonClicked = function(idNumber,collegeName){
  sessionStorage.setItem("id", idNumber);
  sessionStorage.setItem("collegeName",collegeName);
  angular.forEach($scope.data, function(x) {
    var name = JSON.stringify(x.collegeName); // gets the data value in a row in the column collegeName
    var temp = JSON.stringify(collegeName); // gets the data value from the college selected on the first screen

    alert("From Database: " + name.split('(')[0] );
    alert("From College Picked: " + temp);
    console.log(name + "  " + temp);
    console.log(name.split("(")[0] + "  " + temp);
    alert(name.split("(")[0] == temp);
  })
}
```

I'm stuck on why "name.split("(")[0] == temp" does not evaluate to true if it had to split a "(". If I do "Grammar School == Grammar School", and didn't have to split at a "(" it evaluates to true. But if I have to evaluate "Programming School == Programming School" from one of the locations listed above that had a location in parenthesis, it does not evaluate to true.

When I print out "console.log(name.split("(")[0] + "  " + temp);" it will give me this "Programming School  "Programming School" if it had to split at a "(". The first Programming School does not end in quotations, I think that is my problem, but I am not sure.

Comment: It's hard to be sure since you haven't shared the actual data, but my guess would be that the issue is that `"Programming School (Alaska)".split("(")[0] == "Programming School "` <-- note the space

Comment: A simple fix might be to use `.split(" (")[0]` <-- note space before the paren

Comment: Is this your actual code? If so, why would you stringify only to split after to make comparisons?

Comment: Oh, @azium makes a good point. Drop the `JSON.stringify(...);` lines and just use `var name = x.collegeName; var temp = collegeName;` This is why you have quotation marks showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretical fix based on comment discussion:

```
angular.forEach($scope.data, function(x)
{
    var name = x.collegeName; // gets the data value in a row in the column collegeName
    var temp = collegeName; // gets the data value from the college selected on the first screen

    alert(name.split(" (")[0] === temp);
})
```

Comment: Yep, all I had to do was drop the JSON.stringify(). Thank you everyone